# Elixir / Ecto / Postgres trying to get integer from query but get char list instead?

Tags: elixir, ecto

This would seem like the simplest thing in the world, but I am trying to get an integer returned from an ecto query:

```
iex(10)> num = Polo.Repo.all(from n in Polo.Account.Number, select: max(n.account))
[debug] QUERY OK source="account_numbers" db=3.0ms queue=0.1ms
SELECT max(a0."account") FROM "account_numbers" AS a0 []
[7024184]

iex(11)> IO.inspect(num)
[7024184]
[7024184]

iex(12)> IO.puts(num)
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   (stdlib) :io.put_chars(:standard_io, :unicode, [[7024184], 10])

iex(12)> num + 1
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    :erlang.+([7024184], 1)
```

The correct number is in fact 7024184, but for some reason, it is not being returned as an integer. It seems to be a char list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Running latest Elixir 1.4.4

Comment: In Elixir, a charlist is just a list of integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Repo.all` always returns a list. Since you're selecting an integer, you get back a list of integers.

If you want to get just one value, you can use `Repo.one`:

```
num = Polo.Repo.one(from n in Polo.Account.Number, select: max(n.account))
# num should be just the integer `7024184` now
```

Comment: Wow, so simple! Thanks for quick reply!